# C++ library to mutate pdb residues

Tags: c++, software, computational-chemistry, pdb

Are there any open source libraries available to mutate PDB protein residues? If so are do you have any examples of them?

Answer (score 1):

The python `PyMOL` library seems to be pretty close to your needs. For example, see [example on mutagenesis](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Mutagenesis). It is Python, not C++; however, you can [get the best of both worlds](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Advanced_Scripting).

However, if you are more interested in the *process* rather than the result, I would suggest taking some PDB IO library, say, [PDB Record IO Libraries from UCSF, open-source, C/C++](http://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/Overview/software.html#pdbio), read your PDB data and write a mutation function according to your needs. With that, you would avoid the development of PDB IO and storage and focus on the interesting parts.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done by the molecular simulation software that you use. For example, in NAMD this can be accomplished using the `psfgen` command (see page 10 of the [user's guide](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/plugins/psfgen/ug.pdf)). The source code for this command is written in C and exposes a TCL interface, so chances are that you can adapt it to your needs. Keep in mind, though, that after you mutate the residue you may need to do a short equilibration run to get a reasonable geometry for your system.